# How to get .bashrc / .profile variables in Scala

Tags: scala

I am unable to get access to the environmental variables in either ~/.bashrc or ~/.profile from Scala. How do I access the environmental variables from a Scala Process? Also I am unable to update the paths like this:

```
Process("myProgram", None, "PATH"-> ".:/path/to/myProgram").!!
```

However this works:

```
Process("/path/to/myProgram",None).!!
```

Works fine. However, when myProgram depends on some environmental variables being set this doesnt work anymore.

1. How do I change the PATH variable from a Scala program?
2. And even better, how can I get Scala to access the environmental variables from .bashrc or .profile. Currently none of those are available.

Thanks for your time and help

Comment: What does `System.getnenv("your env var name")` return in your parent JVM process? Also, has your parent JVM started by a non-login shell (i.e like one without `#!/bin/bash`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do I access the environmental variables from a Scala Process?

The [`util.Properties` object](https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/api/current/scala/util/Properties$.html) offers 3 different methods for inspecting the environmental variables that the Scala process/program has inherited. Here's an example:

```
util.Properties.envOrNone("LC_COLLATE")
//res0: Option[String] = Some(POSIX)
```

> How do I change the PATH variable from a Scala program?

A running process is not allowed to alter its own environment, but it can launch a new process with a modified environment. There are a couple different ways to go about this.

One is to launch the shell of your choice and use shell syntax to make the modifications before invoking the target command.

```
import sys.process._
Seq("sh", "-c", "PATH=$PATH:$HOME/Progs myProg").!!
// a single arg:^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Or you can supply the environment mods as an argument to one of the many overloaded `Process.apply()` methods.

```
import scala.sys.process._
Process("./myProg"
       ,new java.io.File("/full/path/to")
       ,"PATH"->s"${Properties.envOrElse("PATH",".")}:/full/path/to"
       ).!!
```

> ...can I get Scala to access the environmental variables from `.bashrc` or `.profile`?

If your Scala program is launched from a shell with the proper environment then every process launched from your program should inherit the same. If, for whatever reason, your program has not inherited a fully equipped environment then the easiest thing to do is to launch a fully equipped shell to launch the target command.

```
import scala.sys.process._
Seq("sh", "-c" , ". $HOME/.bashrc && myProg").!!
```